# Is $HN/N$ equal to $H/N$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

The question might be stupid but I was wondering if $(HN)/N = H/N$. It seems true, but in the second isomorphism theorem, one can show that $H/(H\cap N)$ is isomorphic to $HN/N$. So it's weird if the former is true.

Comment: Depends. If $N\le H$ then $HN=H$ and there's nothing weird.

Comment: But you should have told us what you know about $H$ and $N$. We are quite good at guessing games, but even so :-) Anyway, for $H/N$ to make sense, you need $N$ to be contained in $H$. For it to be a group you need $N\unlhd H$. But, you should still confirm whether there is a $G$, lurking in somewhere, such that $H\le G$ and $N\unlhd G$ :-)

Comment: Yes of course, I am really sorry. Thank you for your answer ! I get it !

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes. Let's suppose $H\leq G, N\trianglelefteq G$. We can define a projection homomorphism $\pi:G\to G/N$ by $g\to gN$. Then it is true that $\pi(H)=\pi(HN)$. So what you can "imagine" as $H/N$ is really equal to $HN/N$ as a set of elements. But in order to think of it as a quotient group we want $N$ to be contained in $H$. Since it is not always the case we talk about $HN/N$ instead.

Comment: Thank you ! I get it !